# Avoid code duplication

Tags: perl

```
 if($DSTIP =~ s/(\.)(\d{1,6}$|\w{2,6})$//g){
             $dstip = $dinterface->("$DSTIP");
             $dstport = $PORTS->("$2");
     }
if($DSTIP =~ s/(\.)(\d{1,6}$|\w{2,6})$//g){
             $dstip = $dinterface->("$DSTIP");
             $dstport = $PORTS->("$2");
     }
```

I'm trying to rewrite the code above single line. I tried :

```
      if($SRCIP && $DSTIP  =~ s/(\.)(\)l{1,6}$|\w{2,6})$//g){
        ($srcip, $dstip) = ($dinterface->("$SRCIP"), $dinterface->("$DSTIP"));
        ($srcport, $dstport) = ($PORTS->("$2"), $PORTS->("$2"));
 }
```

Not working for me.

Comment: And now? What's the question?

Comment: `string && string =~ regex`? might want to take a long hard look at that...

Comment: It looks like you may have a copy/paste error in first version of the code ?

Comment: Tip for avoiding code duplication: don't copy/paste the same piece of code twice. ;-)

Comment: Tips for survive SO: follow the [tour] and [ask] and ignore nitpicking comments which doesn't want help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to reuse the same code with different data, you put that in a function. Note that in your case there are some variables involved that are in a (more or less) global scope. `$dinterface` and `$PORTS` would be accessible from the function, but are not defined there. That is bad practice.

```
sub parse_ip {
  my ( $ip ) = @_;

  return ( $dinterface->($ip), $PORTS->($2) )
      if $ip && $ip  =~ s/(\.)(\)l{1,6}$|\w{2,6})$//g;
  return ( undef, undef );
}

# later
my ($dstip, $dstport) = parse_ip($DSTIP);
my ($srcip, $srcport) = parse_ip($SRCIP);
```